# Facebook / FBML - Can I create an Iframe, using FBML, in a Tab on a Profile Page?

Tags: facebook, fbml

I want to create an Iframe within a Tab on a facebook profile. Are there any tag restrictions inside of a Tab or on a Profile Page?

Example profile/tag setup: http://www.facebook.com/#!/AvonProductsInc?v=app_10442206389&ref=ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are restrictions on what FMBL you can include on a profile page. One of these restrictions is no iframes on profile pages.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/iframe

> [fb:iframe] inserts an  tag into an application canvas page; **you cannot use the tag on the profile page** (that is, application tabs and profile boxes)

Answer (score 1):

Good news - iFrames are now supported on tabs.  In fact, it looks like FBML will be disallowed on new tabs after March 11, 2011.

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462

Comment: I wouldn't call it good news, they're still removing _all_ tabs from profile pages. Thanks for the update though!

Comment: Actually that's a good point, it's too easy to confuse the page tabs with the profile tabs.  At what point should the question or answer become a "wiki" where we can update the info.  I wasn't sure if this was worth a new answer in the first place (and now it seems "no"), but didn't feel comfortable editing the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

As Jason mentioned, you can now use iFrames in your Page Tabs. But, in order to work around the issue user613346 mentioned you have to "upgrade" your page.

To upgrade your page, view the page when you're logged in as a page admin. You should see a button at the top that prompts you to preview or upgrade the page.

Upgrading the page switches to the new layout which moves the nav to the left side (and a few other minor things). It also lets iFrames work inside your tabs.

This isn't very well documented. Hope is saves someone else from pulling their hair out.