# Deprecating FBML

Tags: facebook, iframe, fbml, deprecated, facebook-page

As you probably already know (or read quote at the end of this post), Facebook is deprecating FBML in favor of iframes for developping applications.

I am currently launching a new browser plug in and need a landing tab on my facebook page with personalized install buttons and all the useful features one can wish to have on a fan page.

However, I cannot use an iframe in my page because Facebook forbids it (see SO related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915267/facebook-fbml-can-i-create-an-iframe-using-fbml-in-a-tab-on-a-profile-page)) and I am told not to use FBML because it is being deprecated.

**Question is the following: What should I use then ?**

*(I did ask my question on the fbexchange website but got no answer so far (posted 3 days ago))*

---

Quoted from http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/

> We are in the process of deprecating
>   FBML. If you are building a new
>   application on Facebook.com, please
>   implement your application within an
>   iframe, using our JavaScript SDK and
>   Social Plugins. While there is still
>   functionality that we have not ported
>   over yet, we are no longer adding new
>   features to FBML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although Facebook are deprecating FBML they will continue to support it for applications that are currently built with it. What they mean by deprecation is that they will not allow any NEW applications to use FBML come 2011. You have two choices as far as I can see:

1. Facebook have confirmed that pages will have iFrames when FBML is deprecated. So you can wait for this change to happen and then use your iFrame.
2. Make your application with FBML NOW and it will be fine, however, obviously this is not a good long term solution.

If your launch is imminent then my advice would be to bite the bullet and create both the iFrame and FBML version and simply switch when iFrame's become activated for pages.

Comment: Thanks you for answering. I find it pretty stupid coming from Facebook to disable iframes and saying not to use FBML when there is no other alternative. I guess it is just not the right time to start a complex Facebook page.

Comment: @Gaël There never will be. What you want now will become more possible but then your expectations will exceed that. :) such is the way of the coder.

Answer (score 2):

This should no loner be an issue -- iFrames are now supported on Page tabs:
http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/