# FBML is being deprecated?

Tags: facebook, fbml, deprecated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deprecating FBML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275757/deprecating-fbml)

Hi guys,

I was thinking to integrate some facebook experiences in my web pages, but I found this message about FBML:

> We are in the process of deprecating FBML. If you are building a new application on Facebook.com, please implement your application using HTML, JavaScript and CSS. You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML. While there is still functionality that we have not ported over yet, we are no longer adding new features to FBML.

But it says: "You can use our JavaScript SDK and Social Plugins to embedded many of the same social features available in FBML."

When I generated the code for the facebook like button from the social plugins page, I do get tage named  in the code generated. If am not mistaken, isn't this a FBML tag???

Can anyone shed some light on this because I think am a bit confused!

Thanks in advance,
Cheers!

Comment: this is somehow indirectly related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275757/deprecating-fbml

Answer (score 2):

What you get when you're generating the Tags is **XFBML**. This is displayed by the Javascript SDK as Like-Buttons or Comment-Boxes or whatever you've generated.
(BTW if you inspect them with Firebug or similiar, they get parsed into iframes too.)

If you're going to write a Facebook application, develop it using an iframe, the Javascript SDK and whatever you prefer on the backend (there are some SDK's available too).

You'll be fine, it's basically the same. XFBML has a lot of the FBML functionality anyway and the rest (and even more) can be done with the SDK with no problems.