# Is XFBML being Deprecated?

Tags: html, fbml, deprecated, facebook-social-plugins, xfbml

According to Facebook, FBML has been deprecated and will be removed on July 5th 2012, as quoted [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fbml/).

**This is not a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4275757/deprecating-fbml) as I am referring to XFBML not FBML.**

My question is quite simple, as a result of FBML being deprecated, does this mean that XFBML is also being deprecated?

I am asking this because I am using plugins such as the comments Social Plugin and this uses a mixture of XFBML and iframes. Should I change all these plugins to use iframes or HTML5 instead? Or is XFBML not related to FBML?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, xfbml is more like `HTML + FBMl`

XFBML can still be rendered using the Facebook Javascript API, so it's not as bad an idea to use XFBML, but still not the best idea.

Regular HTMl and javascript combined with the Facebook Javascript API can do everything XFBML can do, and it can do it more cleanly.

FYI: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/568/

> Please Note: Our deprecation of FBML does not impact XFBML (eXtended
>   Facebook Markup Language). XFBML is a set of XML elements that can be
>   included in your HTML pages to display Social Plugins. When your page
>   is loaded, any XFBML elements found in the document are processed by
>   the JavaScript SDK, resulting in the appropriate plugin being rendered
>   on your page. The JavaScript SDK will continue to support XFBML after
>   the deprecation of FBML (save for the fb:serverFbml element which is
>   used to execute FBML on our servers).

Comment: Dont know how you found that!!!!!, but that is exactly what I wanted to know. Thank you very much. Will accept when I can. +1

Comment: @BenCarey, I found it by just googling "fbml deprecated" (without quotes). First result points to the page Venu posted. Ironically, if you search for "xfbml deprecated", first result points to this page, with the Facebook developers blog post being the second result xD.

Comment: @Pere The reason you found it is that I posted this question over two years ago! Thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 0):

XFBML uses an XML namespace for the facebook elements on your webpage whereas iframes and HTML5 does not.
An iframe element is a deprecated element and should be avoided where possible.

An XML namespace tells more about an element than a regular div or iframe. So unless you need to enclose an element that has to use local resources (like a youtube movie does) I would always advise that you should use the eXtensible Markup method.

In this case it uses no local resources so I advise you to take the high road on this and use XFBML.

To answer your question directly: No XFBML is not being deprecated, the FBML spec is.

Comment: "An iframe element is a deprecated element" - an `iframe` is _not_ a deprecated element. (?)

Comment: Hi user82217, an iframe was on the list for deprecation in the XHTML spec medio 2015-2016.

Comment: While it can still be used, it is not smart developing for the avarage webdeveloper to use this, unless you really need to.