# Best use of Facebook SDK + html5 vs xfbml

Tags: facebook, html, xfbml

I've implemented the JavaScript SDK in my website as stated on the facebook JavaScript SDK site.:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'YOUR_APP_ID', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>
```

But in the like plugin code section it gives me this code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=YOUR_APP_ID";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

**My 1st question: What is the better code? and are their any differences?**

My second question is about the HTML5 or XFBML rendering of the buttons or comment boxes. I run a wordpress blog, that's not html5.

**My 2nd question: What is the best code to use, the HTML5 or the XFBML? and is one faster that the other, or one less supported than the other?**

Thanks!

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11206747/601466

Answer (score 5):

The first solution loads the Facebook JavaScript library asynchronously, and would provide faster page rendering for your visitors if arranged correctly. Place the `<div id=fb-root">` and `window.fbAsyncInit` definition just after your `<body>` tag so they are defined up front before the Facebook JavaScript library loads.

In contrast, the `function(d)` definition should be located at the bottom of your page before the `</body>` tag thereby delaying Facebook library loading until all your other page elements have loaded above. This ensures your own salient page elements render first.

The `function(d,s,id)` code snippet looks newer (more parameters), but I don't think its asynchronously loading like the first. Therefore, for the time being, I would use the older (first) version for now until Facebook posts an asynchronous version of the newer `function(d,s,id)` code snippet.

---

On your second question, I would continue using the XFBML code implementation until very few of your website visitors are using IE7 or IE8 any longer. Once they have moved on to IE9+, then I would switch to the HTML5 implementation, which has many semantic advantages for search engines, screen readers, and scrapers.

Comment: Hi Mark! Thanks for the great answer. I was wondering if i need to close the first part of the code with </script> and put the last part of the code at the bottom in a <script> of do you need to leave that as it is?

Comment: If you're spiting up the first asynchronous solution, yes you need to place <script></script> around each split part. Be sure to locate the Facebook library load function, `function(d)`, after any JavaScript that affects elements rendered on the page because you want action on those elements first, but before any asynchronous lib loads (e.g. Google Analytics) that don't affect page rendering.